# Combinatorics(permutations, variations and combinations)

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can k married couples be seated in a row of n chairs such that the pairs sits next to each other.?

Please help me in this question, am not sure to use which formula but am definitely sure its without repetition

Comment: Should we assume that $n = 2k$?

Answer (score 0):

I assume $n=2m$ is even. If the couples must sit next to each other, then you really have just $k$ objects (the couples) to be placed in $m$ boxes, and order matters. This is $k!/(k-m)!$

This comes from considering all permutations of the couples and ignoring those that were not seated.